# Find files with a specific folder name anywhere in their path

Tags: bash, file, find

I'm using

`find ./*/*/*/FOO/*/*/!(!(*.tif)|*v.tif) -type f`

to get all tiff files that do NOT end with `v.tif` in a directory tree. How do I edit the command to find files with `FOO` **anywhere** in their path? I came across globstar but it doesn't seem to be available on mac's default bash.

Bonus question: what would be the Windows prompt/Powershell equivalent for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To have `FOO` anywhere in their full path name:

```
find . -type f -wholename "*FOO*"
```

additionally to end with `.tif` and exclude `*v.tif`:

```
find . -type f -wholename "*FOO*[^v].tif"
```

but the above one excludes the edge case of `*FOO.tif`, so this is better:

```
find . -type f -wholename "*FOO*.tif" ! -name "*v.tif"
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're already using `shopt`'s `extglob`. Add `globstar`.

```
shopt -s globstar
```

Then

```
find **/FOO/**/ -type f ! -name '*v.tif'
```

For just TIF's

```
find **/FOO/**/* -type f -name '*.tif' ! -name '*v.tif'
```

Comment: This will not even look in non-FOO directories.

Comment: globstar isn't available on mac's default bash :( and I don't feel like Brew installing another Bash and making it the default

Comment: Well, crap. `-wholename`'s your best bet then.

Comment: +1 for good answer. Also this will look into non-FOO, as it returns `any/thing/FOO.tif`. Also I didn't expect that `-wholename` would be faster, I assume this is similar to the `-name "*"` expanding internally by (super command) `find` and not by the shell.

Comment: Did you test that? Doesn't for me. Should ONLY look in paths that include `FOO` as a complete directory name. Still, I removed the superfluous `*` off the end of the path.

Comment: Yes, tested. If you remove last `/*`, then it doesn't return `anything/FOO.tif` (it depends if we want it or not) but still was slower for me. Probably because bash expands this, not `find` (I'm not sure for this).

Answer (score 1):

for powershell

```
Get-ChildItem -Path <path> -Recurse -Filter *FOO*.tif -Exclude *v.tif
```

Use this for including FOO in directory names as well

```
Get-ChildItem -Path c:\ASB -Recurse -Filter *.tif -Exclude *v.tif -Include *FOO*
```

more general solution

```
 Get-ChildItem -Path c:\ASB -Recurse -Filter *.tif -Exclude *v.tif | Where-Object FullName -like *FOO*
```

Comment: I haven't tried this yet but it seems it won't include any tiff files, right? I just want to filter out the ones ending with "v". And ```FOO``` is a directory, how does this *FOO*.txt work?

Comment: you can change that part. I made a typo :)

Comment: sorry I don't fully understand yet. I was able to list the files with ```Get-ChildItem -Path . -Recurse -Include *.tif -Exclude *v.tif``` but the -Filter part isn't working. The files are not directly under ```FOO```, I need all files that have FOO in some point of their path.

Comment: including directory name?

Comment: yes. -Filter *FOO* returns all ```FOO``` directories in my tree but *FOO*.tif returns nothing. -Filter *.tif -Include *FOO* gives me nothing as well

Comment: Now it works, thanks! I chose the other answer as correct because Powershell was just the bonus question. Also edited your answer to filter out just ```*v.tif```